# I bought a scam token. Cannot sell ! But the sandwich bot can buy and sell. How is that?

Tags: erc-20, scam

I bought a scam token. Cannot sell ! But the sandwich bot can buy and sell. How is that?

Contract address is 0x1ebb7e40c24eb100b68d1289ec2ac130f66eb77d

Comment: Usually, the bot address is enabled by the scammer to any operation they want.